# Terminal (bash) - mkdir from read input string

Tags: bash, macos, input, terminal, mkdir

I am using Terminal (bash) in OSX and trying to create an executable script that will create a directory from input, but I'm having problems when inputting a string with spaces (and I need spaces).

For example, when inputting "new folder" in the code below, it will create two folders named "new" and "folder" of course.

```
read dName; mkdir $dName
```

But with the code below, for some reason I am getting a folder named this: "%80%9D

```
read dName; mkdir "$dName"
```

If I put the second code into terminal WITHOUT using an executable script, it works. I'm not sure why using an executable script to run it gives me "%80%9D instead of the folder name. Please help if possible.

Comment: Are you sure you are using regular ASCII quotes in your code, or are you using curly quotes? A right curly quote `”` happens to have `E2 80 9D` as its UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You are using curly quotes, not regular ASCII quotes, in your script. Your script is UTF-8 encoded, which means the argument to `mkdir` is stored as the following byte stream:

- `e2 80 9c` - left curly quote
- `24 64 4e 61 6d 65` - `$dbash`
- `e2 80 9d` - right curly quote

However, when the script is *run*, those bytes appear to be interpreted using ISO-Latin-1. Since `e2` is a valid byte for an identifier name, and the curly quotes do not actually escape anything, `bash` sees `$dBash%E2` as the expansion of a single, undefined variable, which expands to the empty string. Thus, `mkdir` receives `%e2%80%9c%90%9d` as its argument. The requested filename is created. When listing the directory, the first three bytes are again interpreted as UTF-8 to display a left curly quote, but the remaining two have no interpretation and are shown as-is.

Comment: Take-home message: edit code with a *text* editor, not a word processor.